# How to rank highest to lowest for multiple frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data frame:

```
structure(list(Player = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C"), UnitID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Frame = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 
11L), Side = c("Left", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", 
"Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", 
"Right"), Y = c(3.52, 1.56, 0.54, 3.22, 4.81, 1.1, 1.7, 4.3, 
3.3, 1.8, 1.2, 3.8, 3.5, 1.9, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

I would like to add a column that numbers each player by their Y location when the Frame is equal to 11. Using the y location column, I would like players to be ranked from the highest value down if their "side" column is equal to "Left," and from the lowest value up if their "side" column is equal to right. So the above table would become:

```
structure(list(Player = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C"), UnitID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Frame = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 
11L), Side = c("Left", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", 
"Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", 
"Right"), Y = c(3.52, 1.56, 0.54, 3.22, 4.81, 1.1, 1.7, 4.3, 
3.3, 1.8, 1.2, 3.8, 3.5, 1.9, 1.2), Num = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Just to be clear on what I'm looking for, players A, B, C, and D all hold the same 'num' value throughout all the frames of UnitId=1, and that value is based on their individual Y values in FrameID 11. In frame 11, the player with the highest Y value whose 'side' value is 'left' is assigned 1, and the player with the second highest Y value who also is 'left' is assigned 2 in the num column. The opposite is true of players with a 'side' value of 'right' (ranked from the "bottom up"). It's important to note that the num column needs to hold true for every all FrameIds within the same UnitId.

My apologies if that's confusing, thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach (`df` is the first dataframe in your question)

```
ave(within(df, Num <- 0L), df$UnitID, FUN = function(sd) {
  sd$Num <- with(sd, {
    f11 <- Frame == 11
    y <- Y[f11]
    left <- Side[f11] == "Left"
    right <- !left
    x <- integer(length(y))
    names(x) <- Player[f11]
    x[left] <- rank(-y[left], ties.method = "min")
    x[right] <- rank(y[right], ties.method = "min")
    x[Player]
  })
  sd
})
```

Here is a `dplyr` approach

```
df %>% 
  group_by(UnitID) %>% 
  mutate(Num = local({
    f11 <- Frame == 11
    y <- y[f11]
    left <- Side[f11] == "Left"
    right <- !left
    x <- integer(length(y))
    names(x) <- Player[f11]
    x[left] <- rank(-y[left], ties.method = "min")
    x[right] <- rank(y[right], ties.method = "min")
    unname(x[Player])
  }))
```

Output

```
   Player UnitID Frame  Side    Y Num
1       A      1    10  Left 3.52   1
2       B      1    10 Right 1.56   1
3       C      1    10 Right 0.54   2
4       D      1    10  Left 3.22   2
5       A      1    11  Left 4.81   1
6       B      1    11 Right 1.10   1
7       C      1    11 Right 1.70   2
8       D      1    11  Left 4.30   2
9       A      1    12  Left 3.30   1
10      B      1    12 Right 1.80   1
11      C      1    12 Right 1.20   2
12      D      1    12  Left 3.80   2
13      A      2    11  Left 3.50   1
14      B      2    11 Right 1.90   2
15      C      2    11 Right 1.20   1
```

Comment: What does "sd" refer to?

Comment: It's just the name that I defined for `function(sd) {...}`. I used that name because I wanted to refer to the **s**ubset of **d**f. @rogues77

Comment: Ah, I see that's a clever name. Unfortunately I am getting the following error ```Error: Can't combine `time` <character> and `x` <double>```

Comment: Not sure why that is, seeing as how I have no variable named "time"

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Using this [online R console](https://rextester.com/PMR54724), I get the desired output. Therefore, I assume that either you have modified part of my code or the dataframe is not the same as the one shown above. Can you perhaps show me the code you used and/or part of the real dataframe? @rogues77

Comment: sure, how may I message it to you?

Comment: @rogues77 I think you can just update the question with the code you have tried and a gooledrive/onedrive/dropbox link to your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225590/discussion-between-rogues77-and-ekoam).

Comment: I made a slight mistake when describing what I needed in the column. I left a message in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(Frame == 11)  %>% 
  group_by(UnitID, Side) %>% 
  mutate(num = rank(sign(+(Side == "Right") - 0.5) * Y)) %>% 
  select(Player, UnitID, Side, num) %>% 
  left_join( df1, . , by = c("Player", "UnitID", "Side"))
```

```
#>    Player UnitID Frame  Side    Y num
#> 1       A      1    10  Left 3.52   1
#> 2       B      1    10 Right 1.56   1
#> 3       C      1    10 Right 0.54   2
#> 4       D      1    10  Left 3.22   2
#> 5       A      1    11  Left 4.81   1
#> 6       B      1    11 Right 1.10   1
#> 7       C      1    11 Right 1.70   2
#> 8       D      1    11  Left 4.30   2
#> 9       A      1    12  Left 3.30   1
#> 10      B      1    12 Right 1.80   1
#> 11      C      1    12 Right 1.20   2
#> 12      D      1    12  Left 3.80   2
#> 13      A      2    11  Left 3.50   1
#> 14      B      2    11 Right 1.90   2
#> 15      C      2    11 Right 1.20   1
```

Check to see if the result is the same as OP's expected output:

```
all(df2 == .Last.value)
#> [1] TRUE
```